# htaccess condition for redirecting more than one folder

Tags: .htaccess, conditional-statements

I want to do the following:

- show the content of mydomain.com/folder1/page1.php on mydomain.com/page1
- show the content of mydomain.com/folder2/page2.php on mydomain.com/page2

There would be more than one pages in a folder...

You can do this with one folder like this:

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ folder1/$1.php [L]
```

With 2 folders, the following will not work because the first rule will screw page2 up:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ folder1/$1.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ folder2/$1.php [L]
```

So I need a rewrite condition, thought the following would work but it doesn't:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/folder2/(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ folder1/$1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/folder1/(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ folder2/$1.php [L]
```

Could anyone help me finding a correct condition so that one rule doesn't mess with the other one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#check if file exists in folder 1
RewriteCond        folder1%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder1/$1.php [L]

#otherwise check if file exists in folder 2
RewriteCond        folder2%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder2/$1.php [L]
```